# Can we think of non-symmetric product data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, cartesian-product, category-theory, monoids

[`Control.Category.Constrained.Cartesian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Cartesian) is a class for monoidal categories with some natural transformations (the product is `(,)` and the unit defaults to `()`; the product cannot be changed, unlike the sum in [`Control.Category.Constrained.CoCartesian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:CoCartesian)).

- `regroup` and `regroup'` are for `(a, (b, c)) ≅ ((a, b), c)`;
- `attachUnit` and `detachUnit` are for `a ≅ (a, unit)`.

They *almost* give us the monoid. The only thing that is left is `(unit, a) ≅ a`. Here we use `(,)` being symmetrical: `(a, b) ≅ (b, a)`.

As far as I know, it is not a general property. Bartosz Milewski attributes the property to symmetrical monoidal categories (for example, [here](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/05/13/enriched-categories/)).

Is there some product type in Haskell which is not symmetrical?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-commutative operation on types (there might be a simpler example but I'm out of imagination):

```
type a /\!! b = (a, ((b -> Void) -> Void))
```

**Updated:** it's actually not monoidal because it's missing a (left-)identity. It's associative and non-commutative. Let's say it's close enough.

The intuition is that the second component is the proposition "Not (Not b)", which is NOT equivalent to "b" in intuitionistic logic (so `(/\!!)` is not commutative), but it is equivalent to "Not (Not (Not (Not b))" (so `(/\!!)` is associative).

This also relies on `(b -> Void) -> Void` being a practically useless type, in the sense that all inhabitants are observationally equal, so we can identify logical equivalence with isomorphism of types.

(Technically, the notion of "isomorphism" is relative to a notion of "equality/equivalence" on inhabitants, and for the purpose of this example we choose observational equality.)

For associativity (using `(/\)` as infix notation for `(,)`)

```
   a /\!! (b /\!! c)
=  a /\ Not (Not (b   /\ Not (Not c))
  {- distribute (Not (Not _)) over (/\)) -}
=  a /\ (Not (Not b)  /\ Not (Not (Not (Not c))))
=  a /\ (Not (Not b)  /\ Not (Not c))
  {- associativity of (/\) -}
= (a /\  Not (Not b)) /\ Not (Not c)
= (a /\!! b) /\!! c
```

It's also worth noting that there is an artificial limitation of this being about types. The constrained-categories package makes that arbitrary requirement that categories have types as objects. In general, objects and morphisms in a category can be anything.

To give another example (really, a family of examples), any monoid corresponds to a monoidal category, where the objects are the elements of the monoid, and there are only identity morphisms (it is a [discrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_category)). Pick any non-commutative monoid, then viewed as a discrete category with a product on objects, it is monoidal and non-symmetric.

---

Side remark: in spite of the name of the class `Cartesian`, its definition and description most closely resemble the conventional notion of symmetric monoidal categories, as you've remarked. The documentation warns against potential confusion with "cartesian closed categories", but there is an even more closely related concept of ["cartesian monoidal categories"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_monoidal_category). The `Cartesian` class from this library is missing some crucial members to be considered an approximation of that rather than the more general notion of symmetric monoidal categories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a bit lost though: if `Not (Not b)` is not always equivalent to `b`, how does `() /\!! a ≅ a` hold?

Comment: Oh shoot, that's the one thing I overlooked, and I got it wrong!

Comment: “its definition and description most closely resemble the conventional notion of symmetric monoidal categories” – right. The reason I did not call the class `Monoidal` was because that's the name of [the class of monoidal functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Constrained.html#g:1). I guess `SymmetricMonoidal` would have been an option, but that's a mouthful and `Monoidal` is hard to abbreviate while retaining its meaning.